# How to add url to index.html

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML page that I want to show with a custom URL.

Currently I have only one site [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and that URL is showing on Google and in the addressbar of my browser. But how can I make that when someone goes to my site that it looks like [www.mysite.com/my-keyword](http://www.mysite.com/my-keyword)

So basically what I want to do is to show my site with a fixed URL that have the keyword in it: [www.mysite.com/my-keyword](http://www.mysite.com/my-keyword)

Do I need to make a extra page? My initial thought was to make one Index.html with a http-redirect to my second page, so Index.html + my-keyword.html or is there a simpler way?

I want to achieve this because for Google search results.

**Edit:** I am using HTML only. But I could use PHP or JavaScript too if someone has a solution for that.

Comment: You are using HTML only?

Comment: For this you need to register a domain(i.e. "buy" the www.mysite.com URL from a domain vendor).

Comment: google url rewriting.  As you are able to use  php, [check this post for ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should read a little bit about [URL's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). The thing you call a "keyword" is refered to as "path".

It's possible to use a meta tag in the `<head>`section and redirect the user to another location like this:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/page2">
```

You could also change the value of the adress bar with JavaScript, but that's probably not what you want.

You might want to restate your question with more details about what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a good solution and I will try it. Do I have to make the on-page SEO on the Index.html (meta tags for Google) or on the 2nd page? I just want to make sure that Google can find my site and that everything looks good in the Google search results.